# ggplot `expand_scale()` for the axes - inconsistent

Tags: r, ggplot2

---

#### Example 1

```
library(tidyverse)
ggplot(mtcars) +
  geom_bar(aes(x = factor(cyl))) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = expand_scale(mult = c(0, 0)))
```

[image: 1]

My issue seems to be that ggplot `expand_scale()` is not consistent in its behavior. But that statement is probably incorrect. Let's start with the plot above as our baseline and dig into this.

---

#### Example 2

[If I understand the argument correctly](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/expand_scale.html), `mult = c(X, Y)` allows me the ability to expand ggplot scales X% below the plot, and Y% above the plot. That's what I get with this code below.

```
ggplot(mtcars) +
  geom_bar(aes(x = factor(cyl))) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = expand_scale(mult = c(1, 0)))
```

[image: 2]

---

#### Example 3

```
ggplot(mpg %>% filter(displ > 6, displ < 8), aes(displ, cty)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  facet_grid(vars(drv), vars(cyl)) + 
  geom_text(aes(label = trans)) +
  scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0, 0)) +
  coord_cartesian(clip = "off")
```

[image: 3]

Here's the next baseline I want to work off for examples three and four.

---

#### Example 4

```
ggplot(mpg %>% filter(displ > 6, displ < 8), aes(displ, cty)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  facet_grid(vars(drv), vars(cyl)) + 
  geom_text(aes(label = trans)) +
  scale_x_continuous(expand = c(1, 0)) +
  coord_cartesian(clip = "off")
```

[image: 4]

Using the same logic as in example one I'd think `mult = c(X, Y)` allows me the ability to expand ggplot scales X% to the left of the plot, and Y% to the right of the plot. BUT, my `scale_x_continuous(expand = c(1, 0))` doesn't seem to expand the scale `1 = 100%` to the left of the plot and `0 = 0%` to the right of the plot.

This `scale_x_continuous(expand = c(1, 0))` instead puts some extra space to the left of the plot and a lot more extra space to the right of the plot?

What is happening? Why?

---

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This:

```
expand = c(<some number>, <some number>)
```

is **NOT** the same as this:

```
expand = expand_scale(mult = c(<some number>, <some number>))
```

From `?expand_scale`, we can see the full set of default parameters for the function is this:

```
expand_scale(mult = 0, add = 0)
```

Where both `mult` & `add` can have length 1 (same value applied to lower / upper limits) or length 2 (first value applies to lower limit, second to upper).

The form `expand = c(...)`, on the other hand, can accept a vector of either length 2 or 4. If it's a vector of length 2, the first value is mapped to `mult` and the second value to `add`, so `expand = c(1, 0)` is equivalent to `expand = expand_scale(mult = 1, add = 0)`, which adds 100% expansion on ***both*** lower and upper limits. If it's a vector of length 4, the first two values are mapped to the lower limits for `mult` followed by `add`, and the last two values are mapped to the respective upper limits.

Let's use the same plot for illustration:

```
p <- ggplot(mpg %>% filter(displ > 6, displ < 8), aes(displ, cty)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  facet_grid(vars(drv), vars(cyl)) + 
  geom_text(aes(label = trans)) +
  coord_cartesian(clip = "off")
```

The following three variations will produce the same plot:

```
p + scale_x_continuous(expand = expand_scale(mult = 1, add = 0))
p + scale_x_continuous(expand = expand_scale(mult = 1)) # add = 0 is the default anyway
p + scale_x_continuous(expand = c(1, 0))
```

The following two variations will also produce the same plot. (I'm using different expansion values here for illustration, though in general, if you have 4 different expansion values to specify, the `expand_scale()` format is much less ambiguous than listing out all four values in a vector...)

```
p + scale_x_continuous(expand = expand_scale(mult = c(1, 2), add = c(3, 4)))
p + scale_x_continuous(expand = c(1, 3, 2, 4)) # note the difference in order of values
```